# Does $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}x=0$ imply that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}x=0$, does it mean that 
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$?

I tried to use the definition of limit but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Have you seen the proof that differentiability implies continuity? It's the same idea (as you can see if you compare the proof with Ivo Terek's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \to 0$, then $x$ is close to zero, but it is not zero. So we can do: $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{x}x = \lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot \lim_{x \to x_0}x = 0 \cdot x_0 = 0.$$

Comment: But shouldn't $x_0=0$? $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^2=0$ but if $x_0\neq 0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}x^2=x_0^2\neq 0$

Comment: Oh, now I see that you added that the limit was $x \to 0$. I didn't knew, so I used $x \to x_0$, any point. The result is valid for $x$ going to any point.

Comment: I'm not sure but seems you think I'm the OP ("you added" seems to me). The OP is Neil Rauch, I just commented your answer.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. But indeed we're not using that the limit is to zero. I mean that $$\lim_{x \to \text{something}} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to \text{something}} f(x) = 0.$$

We don't ask even for continuity of $f$.

Comment: No problem! The implication in your comment is true, but the something IS $0$. Who knows what happens out of $0$.

Comment: The limit looks at values near $0$, but different from $0$. I still can multiply and divide by $x$ there. My point is: I'm not dividing by zero.

Comment: Yes you can, but it seems to me that  there was probably no need to  change notation. $x\to 0$ and $x\to x_0$ where $x_0\neq 0$ are two totally different thinks.

Comment: Yes, but I *am* allowing $x_0 = 0$ too..

Comment: I see. Guess it's possible instead to express your idea like this: Let $x\in (-\delta, \delta)\backslash\{ 0\}$ where $\delta>0$ (a such neighborhood where $f$ is defined must exist so that the limit has a sense). We have $f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}x$ thus $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x$.

Comment: I think you meant $x \in (x_0 -\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus \{0\}$, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Oh, my bad! You're right that's what I mean, but only for $x_0=0$. We agree!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ exists.
If by contradiction $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=a\neq0$ then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$.